# Rails Active Model Serializers has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I'm using ActiveModelSerializers gem. In my model a User can have many Vehicles

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :vehicles
end

class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

My serializers:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name, :vehicles
end

class VehicleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :color, :make, :model
end
```

Vehicle has more attributes than just color, make and model.

If I print a single vehicle `@vehicle`, then only the fields specified in serializer are displayed. However, if I print `@user` (which includes :vehicles in it's serializer) then the serializer is ignored and all the fields of Vehicle are printed.

I'm guessing it has to to with the fact that user.vehicles is an array and not just one item, but is there a way to print the whole array of a user's vehicles as described in serializer for each item?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AMS supports associations through the `ActiveModel::Serializer::Association` struct. What this means is that you can have in your `UserSerializer` the following:

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :name

  has_many :vehicles
end
```